# Installing Office 2010 on a Windows 8 new computer - SP2 Issue

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office-2010, service-pack

I am installing office 2010 and I get an error "Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s):  This product requires Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 or above.  Correct the issue(s) listed above and re-run setup."

When I download the SP2 file from Windows, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are both version bit-compatible? Are you installing a 32-bit version of Office with a 32-bit version of Windows 8 or a 64 with a 64?

Comment: Windows Server service packs have nothing to do with Windows 8 altogether. I'm surprised it even let you install it.

Comment: @Ariane Might be referring to the Office 2010 SP2, not the actual Windows Server SP.